# Is there a way to remove jacoco branch coverage in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jacoco

I have a spring boot project in IntelliJ, and I want to remove the jacoco branch coverage for this project, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured that out, just add these lines to pom.xml file, you can configure by youself

```
<jacoco.coverage.line>0.80</jacoco.coverage.line>
<jacoco.coverage.branch>0.80</jacoco.coverage.branch>
```